# How to sort by ID and then detect the specific difference within the same ID and then show all the contents in one data frame?

Tags: r

I asked the similar question previously. [R: How to sort by ID and then detect the difference within the same ID?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59798529/r-how-to-sort-by-id-and-then-detect-the-difference-within-the-same-id)

But this time, I want to show the specific sample IDs within the same ID.
My data frame is

```
dataframe <- data.frame(ID=c("ID1","ID2","ID3","ID4", "ID2", "ID2", "ID3","ID4", "ID5","ID1"), 
                    sample_ID=c(1:10),sample_date=c(1991-05-23, 1991-05-24,1991-05-24, 1991-05-26,1991-05-27,1991-05-28,1991-05-30,1991-05-31, 1991-06-03, 1991-06-03), 
                    sex =c(1,2,1,2,2,2,1,2,1,1), and_so_on1 =c(1), and_so_on2 =c(0))
```

From here,I want to sort by the same ID and detect if the same ID has very close sample_date(e.g. within 1day for this time).
And then I want to show the results like the following,

```
outcome <- data.frame(ID=c("ID2","ID2"), sample_ID=c(5,6),sample_date=c(1991-05-26,1991-05-27),sex=c(2),and_so_on1 =c(1), and_so_on2 =c(0))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by comparing the currenct date with the previous date and lead date with the current date. When this is 1 you select the record.

```
dataframe <- data.frame(ID=c("ID1","ID2","ID3","ID4", "ID2", "ID2", "ID3","ID4", "ID5","ID1"), 
                        sample_ID=c(1:10),
                        sample_date=c("1991-05-23", "1991-05-24","1991-05-24", "1991-05-26","1991-05-27","1991-05-28","1991-05-30","1991-05-31", "1991-06-03", "1991-06-03"), 
                        sex =c(1,2,1,2,2,2,1,2,1,1), 
                        and_so_on1 =c(1), 
                        and_so_on2 =c(0))

library(dplyr)

dataframe %>%
  mutate(sample_date = as.Date(sample_date)) %>%
  arrange(ID, sample_date) %>%
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  filter((sample_date - lag(sample_date)) == 1 |
         (lead(sample_date) - sample_date) == 1)

# A tibble: 2 x 6
# Groups:   ID [1]
  ID    sample_ID sample_date   sex and_so_on1 and_so_on2
  <fct>     <int> <date>      <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>
1 ID2           5 1991-05-27      2          1          0
2 ID2           6 1991-05-28      2          1          0
```

Comment: Thank you, phiver! It is a perfect answer! Could you answer one more? If I want to delete sample_ID 6 after identifying 'and_so_on1' is the same for sample_ID 5 and 6, what should I do?

Comment: You could add the following line of code to the code above: `%>% 
  filter(and_so_on1 == lead(and_so_on1))` This only selects the records where current value of and_so_on1 equals the next one record. In effect it will remove ID6. (In this example at least)